# Android - horizontal scrolling of multiple viewable items

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling, android-viewpager

EDIT: See my own answer for easy solution

**IMPORTANT**: *Bounty is offered for clear way to modify ViewPager to satisfy the scenario outlined below. Please do not offer HorizontalScrollView - I need full Fragment lifecycle scenario covered*

I need to implement horizontal scrolling of `Fragments`-based views in which one item is in the center and items to the right/left are partially or fully visible. `ViewPager` is ill suitable for the task since it's focused on displaying one item at each time.

To make it easier to understand below is a quick sketch in which items 1, 5 and 6 are outside of viewable area. And and want to make this viewable number configurable so for example in portrait view I will only show 2 (or possibly just one) items.

I'm not trying to fit say 3 items on the screen, as long as central item is shown others can be cropped. On the small screen is OK to have 1 central item and as screen grows in size multiple (cropped is OK) items should be shown

I understand that this looks like a gallery but again the items are not simple images but `Fragments` with a vertically scrollable list in each fragment

P.S. Found this blogpost by @Commonsware that [list 3 different approaches](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/20/multiple-view-viewpager-options.html). For my need I like #3

[image]

Comment: This link will help you [HorizontalListView](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34)

Comment: I need to have horizontal scroll of Fragments with each having a vertical ListView

Comment: I have a very similar need. I was using Gallery until it started leaking objects all over the place once I added a ListView to the gallery item views.  Currently thinking about fixing Gallery since that seams easier than trying to fix ViewPager.

Comment: Useful link: http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/20/multiple-view-viewpager-options.html

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This one has surprisingly easy answer, I'm not even sure why it wasn't posted right away. All that I needed to do to get the exact effect was to override `PagerAdapter#getPageWidth` method. By default it returns 1 but if you set it to 0.5 you will get 2 pages, 0.33 will give you 3, etc. Depending on width of the separator between pager items you may have to slightly decrease the value.

See the following snippet:

```
    @Override
    public float getPageWidth(final int position) {
        // this will have 3 pages in a single view
        return 0.32f;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Once I wrote something similar as template. In my example I can scroll with the buttons up and down and sidewise. You could modify it a little bit to fulfill your requirements. In my example I have 4 Views arranged like this:

**1 2**
**3 4**

It looks like this. On the picture I scroll from view 1 to the right to view 2:

[image: Android View Scrolling]

The code consist of this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="350sp"
        android:layout_width="320sp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewContainer"
            android:background="#CCCCCC"
            android:layout_width="640sp"
            android:layout_height="700sp">
        </LinearLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
      <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
            android:layout_width="320sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="1"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
            <TableRow
            android:background="#333333"
            android:gravity="bottom">       
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnUp"
                android:layout_width="60sp"
                android:layout_height="50sp"
                android:text="Lift U"
                />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="60sp"
                android:layout_height="50sp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
            />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="60sp"
                android:layout_height="50sp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
            />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnScreenUp"
                android:layout_width="60sp"
                android:layout_height="50sp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:text="Scrn U"
                />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
              android:background="#444444"
              android:layout_gravity="right">
              <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnDown"
                android:layout_width="60sp"
                android:layout_height="50sp"
                android:text="Lift D"
                />
              <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnEnter"
                android:layout_width="60sp"
                android:layout_height="50sp"
                android:text="Enter"
                />
               <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnScreenLeft"
                android:layout_width="60sp"
                android:layout_height="50sp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:text="Scrn L"
                />
               <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnScreenDown"
                android:layout_width="60sp"
                android:layout_height="50sp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:text="Scrn D"
                />
               <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnScreenRight"
                android:layout_width="60sp"
                android:layout_height="50sp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:text="Scrn R"
                />
            </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

and this Java code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ViewSwitcherTest extends Activity {

    private TextView view1, view2, view3, view4;
    private Button btnUp, btnEnter, btnDown, btnScreenDown, btnScreenUp, btnScreenLeft, btnScreenRight;
    private LinearLayout viewContainer;
//  private TableLayout tableLayout;
    private LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;
    private DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    private int top = 0, left = 0;
    private float density = 1.0f;
//  private ViewSwitcher switcher;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        density = metrics.density;
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
//      Buttons
        btnEnter = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEnter);
        btnUp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnUp);
        btnDown = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDown);
        btnScreenDown = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnScreenDown);
        btnScreenUp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnScreenUp);
        btnScreenLeft = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnScreenLeft);
        btnScreenRight = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnScreenRight);
//      --------
//      tableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
        view1 = new TextView(this);
        view1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.view1);
        view1.setHeight((int)(350*density));
        view1.setWidth((int)(320*density));
        view1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.setMargins(left, top, 0, 0);   
        viewContainer = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.viewContainer);
        viewContainer.addView(view1, layoutParams);
        //Add 2nd view
        view2 = new TextView(this);
        view2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.view2);
        view2.setHeight((int)(350*density));
        view2.setWidth((int)(320*density));
        view2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.setMargins(left, top, 0, 0);
        viewContainer.addView(view2, layoutParams); 
        //Add 3rd view
        view3 = new TextView(this);
        view3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.view3);
        view3.setHeight((int)(350*density));
        view3.setWidth((int)(320*density));
        view3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        top += 350*density;
        left += 640*density*(-1);
        layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.setMargins(left, top, 0, 0);
        viewContainer.addView(view3, layoutParams);     
        //add 4th view
        view4 = new TextView(this);
        view4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.view4);
        view4.setHeight((int)(350*density));
        view4.setWidth((int)(320*density));
        view4.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        top += 0;
        left += 640*density;
        layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.setMargins(left, top, 0, 0);
        viewContainer.addView(view4, layoutParams);     
        btnEnter.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Quit the application for now
                finish();
            }
        });
        btnScreenLeft.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                viewContainer.scrollBy(-10,0);
            }
        });
        btnScreenRight.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                viewContainer.scrollBy(10,0);
            }
        });
        btnScreenUp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                viewContainer.scrollBy(0,-10);
            }
        });
        btnScreenDown.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                viewContainer.scrollBy(0,10);
            }
        });
//      view1.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {            
//          @Override
//          public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
//              if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN)
//                  viewContainer.scrollBy(0,10);
//              return true;
//          }
//      });
    }
}
```

The big numbers on every screen are black background images with those numbers painted on it. (I didn't post it here because you will probably modify the code anyway).

Comment: No, can't go this route. I have much more complicated setup where I'm using ViewPager and FragmentStatePagerAdapter to take care of Fragments life cycle. At this point I'm pretty much set on idea of modifying ViewPager and looking for a hints on which part do I need to modify/extend

Answer (score 1):

We are doing something pretty much exactly like you are describing using a `Gallery` with `Fragments`, and a gallery adapter extending the `BaseAdapter`. I would recommend going with a gallery to achieve your goal (we also use a `ViewPager` for the view where we do not need to see the other fragments).

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to possibly implement this.

1. By a [ViewSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html).
   Here is an excellent [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mGwG8-chUEM) showing how it works with an [onGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html). However, I am not sure if this will work with multiple views like your picture shows.
2. As an alternative, you could use a [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html).
   However, this often causes issues if you have one ScrollView inside of a another, but it may be worth a shot!

Let me know how it goes,
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to MrZander's second answer take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2655740/935075

Comment: Not even close. I don't need "snap to place" or detecting horizontal gestures. All of that is taken care by ViewPager. Please read a bounty note

Answer (score 0):

[Check out this blog post](http://blog.velir.com/index.php/2010/11/17/android-snapping-horizontal-scroll/) on how to write a custom horizontal scroll view to achieve something similar. The example has only one screen visible at a time, but you should be able to easily modify it for your needs.

Comment: I have implementation based on ViewPager that does one screen at the time. I specifically call for multiple/partial views in the bounty

Comment: Right, the code in that example will not do exactly what you want as is, but it is a great place to start. In the example, the inner views are the same width as the outer view (the horizontal scroll view), so naturally, only one of them is visible at a time. You could tweak the code so that your inner views are narrower than the outer scroll view. This will allow more than one of them to be visible at the same time. If you do this, you will also need to tweak the "scrollTo" value so that the middle view is properly centered when the "snap" occurs.

Comment: I'm looking at doing the same with ViewPager. I don't want to go HorizontalScrollView route since then I will be missing a lot of Fragments related functionality of ViewPager

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extend ViewPager just override the draw method, and setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit). But, I recommend using `FragmentPageAdapter` if your fragments themselves are kind of complex.

You can check the source code **[here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.4_r1.2/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java#ViewPager)** or if you want to check the one in the support package you can do it **[here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.android/support-v4/r7/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java#ViewPager)**.

Comment: I'm using FragmentStatePagerAdapter but that takes care of a single Fragment and I need to restructure way the list is positioned on the screen with multiple Fragments in view. I'm aware of code source, thanks

Comment: If the fragments aside from the main one don't need to be active, just shrink the central one with a zoom, and add an image either side that represents the component/fragment. Make the image once, then draw them as you scroll over that zone.

Comment: It does. Especially if you are in the tablet and side fragments are fully visible