# How to create a custom page in ViewPager in which each page has 3 ImageViews( it could vary)?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, horizontal-scrolling

My question is similar to this one, [Android - horizontal scrolling of multiple viewable items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694812/android-horizontal-scrolling-of-multiple-viewable-items). Unfortunately, still could not get the right answer.

I dont want to use HorizontalScrollView as it does not free up the native memory, which is causing me OutOfMemoryError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to create a custom page in ViewPager in which each page has 3 ImageViews( it could vary)?

Step #1: Design a fragment that "has 3 ImageViews( it could vary)"

Step #2: Create a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` that creates pages based on the fragment from step #1

Step #3: Create a `ViewPager` and hand it an instance of your adapter from step #2

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare!! I'm creating the fragment with the required number of imageviews in `getItem` method from `FragmentPagerAdapter`. It works. :)