# How to prevent image selection while Gallery is scrolling?

Tags: android, android-gallery

I'm trying to implement my ownt picrutes gallary app. I'm using ImageSwitche for showing big image and Gallery for showing thumbnails. The problem is that when user scrolls gallery it changes selection to thumbnain whic is in the middle of gallery but required behaviour is just scroll like ListView and change image when user tap on thumbnail.

Does anybody have suggestion how to implement such behaviour.

PS. HorizontalScrollView with LinearLayout inside is bad idea becaus of it does not recycle views and holds all the pictures of thumbnails in the memory.

Comment: We need more information. Code examples, layout examples, ect.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the solution I have for [my own question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694812/android-horizontal-scrolling-of-multiple-viewable-items/13537510#13537510.)

Basically I ended up with slightly modified version of ViewPager to display N-number of pages  instead of just one. The only thing that I don't like about that that you will not have velocity-based scrolling as in ListView

Comment: As far as I understand your implementation scrolls item one by one...
But I need smooth scrolling like in ListView.

Any way I found link to <a href="http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34>blog post</a> with custom Horizontal ListView, hope it will help.