# Disable ListView Scrolling when swiping ViewPager

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager

is there a way to lock the vertical scrolling of a ListView while scrolling an item which is a ViewPager? Or perhaps change the horizontal scrolling sensitivity of the ViewPager?

Thanks.

**LAST EDIT**

Here is my updated solution. Thanks for your replies Masoud Dadashi, your comments finally made me came up with a solution to my problem.

Here is my custom ListView class:

```
public class FolderListView extends ListView {

    private float xDistance, yDistance, lastX, lastY;

    // If built programmatically
    public FolderListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // init();
    }

    // This example uses this method since being built from XML
    public FolderListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // init();
    }

    // Build from XML layout
    public FolderListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // init();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            xDistance = yDistance = 0f;
            lastX = ev.getX();
            lastY = ev.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            final float curX = ev.getX();
            final float curY = ev.getY();
            xDistance += Math.abs(curX - lastX);
            yDistance += Math.abs(curY - lastY);
            lastX = curX;
            lastY = curY;
            if (xDistance > yDistance)
                return false;
        }

        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);

    }
}
```

Comment: Look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900860/viewpager-in-a-listview-how-to-lock-the-scrolling-axis

Answer (score 7, accepted):

yes there is. create another customListView class extended from ListView and override its dispatchTouchEvent event handler like this:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
   if(ev.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
      return true;
   return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

then use this customListView instead

Comment: I gave you an example of disabling scroll but apparently I wan't clear enough. In that overridden method you should detect the gesture and disable scrolling if it is SWIPE. since code is available in the address below I am not duplicating it. look at this address: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646028/android-horizontalscrollview-within-scrollview-touch-handling

Comment: I have updated my post, i followed your instructions and finally managed to achieve the desired functionality. Thank you so much!