# Scroll view in ViewFlipper forces onFling Gesture not working

Tags: android, scrollview, viewflipper

I have implemented a ViewFlipper with 8 child view in my application as follows.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/main_bg"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ViewFlipper 
     android:id="@+id/layout_tab_one"
     android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">

     <include 
        layout="@layout/exterior_driverside_1"
        />
     <include 
         layout="@layout/exterior_driverside_2"
         />
     <include 
         layout="@layout/exterior_front_1"
         />
     <include 
         layout="@layout/exterior_front_2"
         />
     <include 
         layout="@layout/exterior_passenger_1"
         />
     <include 
         layout="@layout/exterior_passenger_2"
         />
     <include 
        layout="@layout/exterior_rear_1"
        />
    <include 
        layout="@layout/interior_1"
        />
    <include 
        layout="@layout/interior_2"
        />
    <include 
        layout="@layout/interior_3"
        />
    <include 
        layout="@layout/interior_4"
        />
    <include 
        layout="@layout/interior_5"
        />
    <include 
        layout="@layout/finalpage"
        />
</ViewFlipper>
</LinearLayout>
```

Each child layout resembles like this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/check_title"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
                    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Exterior / Rear     "
                    />
        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/greytop_bg"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
            android:paddingRight="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
            >


                 <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/tailights_txt"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:text="Tailights"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    />
                   <CheckBox 
                       android:id="@+id/tailights"
                       android:checked="false"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"   />
                   <EditText 
                       android:id="@+id/tailights_edit"
                       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                       android:layout_height="30dp"
                       android:layout_below="@+id/tailights"
                       android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
                       android:hint="Tap to enter comments"
                       android:textSize="10dp"
                       android:visibility="gone"
                       />
                </RelativeLayout>
             <RelativeLayout    
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/greymid_bg"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
            android:paddingRight="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp" >
                 <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/bootlid_txt"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:text="Boot lid / Tailgate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"/>
                   <CheckBox 
                       android:id="@+id/bootlid"
                       android:checked="false"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
                   <EditText 
                       android:id="@+id/bootlid_edit"
                       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                       android:layout_height="30dp"
                       android:layout_below="@+id/bootlid"
                       android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
                       android:hint="Tap to enter comments"
                       android:textSize="10dp"
                       android:visibility="gone"
                       />
                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/greymid_bg"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
            android:paddingRight="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp" >
                 <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/bumperbar_txt"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:text="Bumper Bar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    />
                   <CheckBox 
                       android:id="@+id/bumperbar"
                       android:checked="false"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
                   <EditText 
                       android:id="@+id/bumperbar_edit"
                       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                       android:layout_height="30dp"
                       android:layout_below="@+id/bumperbar"
                       android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
                       android:hint="Tap to enter comments"
                       android:textSize="10dp"
                       android:visibility="gone"
                       />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/greymid_bg"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
            android:paddingRight="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp" >
                 <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/mudflaps_txt"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:text="Mud Flaps"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    />
                   <CheckBox 
                       android:id="@+id/mudflaps"
                       android:checked="false"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
                   <EditText 
                       android:id="@+id/mudflaps_edit"
                       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                       android:layout_height="30dp"
                       android:layout_below="@+id/mudflaps"
                       android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
                       android:hint="Tap to enter comments"
                       android:textSize="10dp"
                       android:visibility="gone"
                       />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/greybott_bg"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
            android:paddingRight="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp" >
                 <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/rear_unapproved_txt3"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:text="Unapproved advertising"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    />
                   <CheckBox 
                       android:id="@+id/rear_unapproved3"
                       android:checked="false"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
                   <EditText 
                       android:id="@+id/rear_unapproved_edit3"
                       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                       android:layout_height="30dp"
                       android:layout_below="@+id/rear_unapproved3"
                       android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
                       android:hint="Tap to enter comments"
                       android:textSize="10dp"
                       android:visibility="gone"
                       />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have implemented onGestureListener(onFling) to switch over another child view of the ViewFlipper. If i put ScrollView for each child view, onFling is not working. But every child view needs a scrollview. How to implement ScrollView in the ViewFlipper ? It will be greatfull if someone suggests some code for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330187/gesture-detection-and-scrollview-issue) helps you

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
    super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);    
    return productGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this really works. Textview scrolls automatically when overflow is there, if you don't handle the swipe gesture of view flipper adapter. So when  you handle the swipe gesture yourself, make your textview scrollable by a adding

```
mTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

And add the `dispatchtouchevent`function shown above, in your Activity.