# View with ViewPager not vertically scrollable in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-constraintlayout, android-nestedscrollview

This feels like a no brainer but somehow I'm stuck. The view won't allow me to scroll it. It's as if the height of the fragment inflated in the `ViewPager` doesn't get calculated. Searching SO suggest I need to write my own `ViewPager` and override `onMeasure()`, but I can't believe I would have to go that far for something as simple as this.

Here is my layout, somewhat simplified for convenience. The `ViewPager` is populated with fragments taking up space way beyond the screen (vertically). Still, nothing on the screen is scrollable. Why is that?

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header_image_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_text_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header_image_view"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/resume_training_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title_text_view"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/lesson_table_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"          
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/resume_training_button">
        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/lesson_table_layout">
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Here's an example view. The Lorem ipsum text continues for long, and I'm expecting the whole screen to be scrollable, but it isn't.

[image: example_view]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just for clarification did you try any other layout ?? like linear or relative inside the scrolV??

Comment: @SantanuSur yes, I've tried them both. Same result. But thanks for the thought. I've also updated the question with an image to clarify my issue.

Comment: but what are you doing white blank space at the top of the viewpager.. you can utilize it..

Comment: An image is suppose to be there.

Comment: do one thing..replace the scrollView with nestedScrollView..and put a linear layout around it.. i am writing the solution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up rewriting it quite a bit. It didn't make sense to scroll above the `TabLayout` so I ended up using a `CoordinatorLayout`, according to

```
<CoordinatorLayout>        <-- width/height = match_parent
    <AppBarLayout>         <-- width = match_parent, height = wrap_content
        <ImageView/>
        <TextView/>
        <Button/>
        <TabLayout/>
    <AppBarLayout/>
    <ViewPager/>           <-- width/height = match_parent, app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
<CoordinatorLayout/>
```

And each fragment inserted in the `ViewPager` is now wrapped in a `NestedScrollView`.

Thanks for the other answers. It'll probably help someone else!

Comment: Brilliant solution! BTW, to make the whole content scrollable(like a `ScrollView`), add a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and set its `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"`.

Answer (score 2):

There is such problem , sometimes the `ScrollView` and the `ViewPager` switch focus.

> If you have a `ViewPager` in a `ScrollView` and you want it always to stay in focus when you touch it and the `ScrollView` never getting a focus, setting the `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent` does that.
>
> ```
>  mViewPager= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
>     mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
>     mViewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
>
>         @Override
>         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
>             mViewPager.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
>             return false;
>         }
>     });
> ```

Look up more answers in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669725/viewpager-inside-scrollview-vertical-scroll-doesnt-work)

EDIT:

Another way I see that may work is setting scrolling to your tablayout like this programmatically

```
tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that does not help. Nothing is scrolling vertically (though the ViewPager is working horizontally). I've updated the question with an image as well to clarify the view.

Comment: Editted my answer, I should you try this one out. If it doesn;t work try making your textview inside the fragment (where you have text on the pic) scrollable and this will be a workaround for you

Answer (score 0):

Try nestedScrollView instead of scrollView.. try the following snippet..

```html
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@id/fragment_detail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    ...Content...
     
     <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/lesson_table_layout">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
   
     </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks, but no luck. And I've tried all variants of this before. I'm keen to think that it's the `onMeasure`'s fault, not the actual view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same layout, I used this with android x android 13 and then I set the height into 0dp and app layout_constraint like this:

```
    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPagerDetails"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/aphidsdetailstab"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```