# Vertical scroll not work when AutoscrollViewpager inside scrollview

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have used AutoscrollViewPager inside NestedScrollview but vertical scroll not worked. i have tried so many solution but not work like below mentioned.

https://stackoverflow.com/7381360/is-it-possible-to-have-a-viewpager-inside-of-a-scrollview

[ViewPager inside ScrollView - vertical scroll doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669725/viewpager-inside-scrollview-vertical-scroll-doesnt-work/54921748)

[HorizontalScrollView within ScrollView Touch Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646028/horizontalscrollview-within-scrollview-touch-handling)

[ViewPager inside ScrollView - vertical scroll doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669725/viewpager-inside-scrollview-vertical-scroll-doesnt-work)

```
 <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/nested_scroll"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:fillViewport="true">
<LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
<FrameLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="250dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="bottom">

                            <com.x.x.AutoScrollViewPager
                                android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="220dp"
                                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                                android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/pager_dots"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:orientation="horizontal" />
                        </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView> 



package com.xx.xx;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.animation.Interpolator;

import androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class AutoScrollViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public static final int        DEFAULT_INTERVAL            = 1500;

    public static final int        LEFT                        = 0;
    public static final int        RIGHT                       = 1;

    /** do nothing when sliding at the last or first item **/
    public static final int        SLIDE_BORDER_MODE_NONE      = 0;
    /** cycle when sliding at the last or first item **/
    public static final int        SLIDE_BORDER_MODE_CYCLE     = 1;
    /** deliver event to parent when sliding at the last or first item **/
    public static final int        SLIDE_BORDER_MODE_TO_PARENT = 2;

    /** auto scroll time in milliseconds, default is {@link #DEFAULT_INTERVAL} **/
    private long                   interval                    = DEFAULT_INTERVAL;
    /** auto scroll direction, default is {@link #RIGHT} **/
    private int                    direction                   = RIGHT;
    /** whether automatic cycle when auto scroll reaching the last or first item, default is true **/
    private boolean                isCycle                     = true;
    /** whether stop auto scroll when touching, default is true **/
    private boolean                stopScrollWhenTouch         = true;
    /** how to process when sliding at the last or first item, default is {@link #SLIDE_BORDER_MODE_NONE} **/
    private int                    slideBorderMode             = SLIDE_BORDER_MODE_NONE;
    /** whether animating when auto scroll at the last or first item **/
    private boolean                isBorderAnimation           = true;
    /** scroll factor for auto scroll animation, default is 1.0 **/
    private double                 autoScrollFactor            = 1.0;
    /** scroll factor for swipe scroll animation, default is 1.0 **/
    private double                 swipeScrollFactor           = 1.0;

    private Handler handler;
    private boolean                isAutoScroll                = false;
    private boolean                isStopByTouch               = false;
    private float downX = 0f;
    private CustomDurationScroller scroller                    = null;

    public static final int        SCROLL_WHAT                 = 0;

    public AutoScrollViewPager(Context paramContext) {
        super(paramContext);
        init();
    }

    public AutoScrollViewPager(Context paramContext, AttributeSet paramAttributeSet) {
        super(paramContext, paramAttributeSet);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        handler = new MyHandler(this);
        setViewPagerScroller();
    }

    /**
     * start auto scroll, first scroll delay time is {@link #getInterval()}
     */
    public void startAutoScroll() {
        isAutoScroll = true;
        sendScrollMessage((long)(interval + scroller.getDuration() / autoScrollFactor * swipeScrollFactor));
    }

    /**
     * start auto scroll
     * 
     * @param delayTimeInMills first scroll delay time
     */
    public void startAutoScroll(int delayTimeInMills) {
        isAutoScroll = true;
        sendScrollMessage(delayTimeInMills);
    }

    /**
     * stop auto scroll
     */
    public void stopAutoScroll() {
        isAutoScroll = false;
        handler.removeMessages(SCROLL_WHAT);
    }

    /**
     * set the factor by which the duration of sliding animation will change while swiping
     */
    public void setSwipeScrollDurationFactor(double scrollFactor) {
        swipeScrollFactor = scrollFactor;
    }

    /**
     * set the factor by which the duration of sliding animation will change while auto scrolling
     */
    public void setAutoScrollDurationFactor(double scrollFactor) {
        autoScrollFactor = scrollFactor;
    }

    private void sendScrollMessage(long delayTimeInMills) {
        /** remove messages before, keeps one message is running at most **/
        handler.removeMessages(SCROLL_WHAT);
        handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(SCROLL_WHAT, delayTimeInMills);
    }

    /**
     * set ViewPager scroller to change animation duration when sliding
     */
    private void setViewPagerScroller() {
        try {
            Field scrollerField = ViewPager.class.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
            scrollerField.setAccessible(true);
            Field interpolatorField = ViewPager.class.getDeclaredField("sInterpolator");
            interpolatorField.setAccessible(true);

            scroller = new CustomDurationScroller(getContext(), (Interpolator)interpolatorField.get(null));
            scrollerField.set(this, scroller);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * scroll only once
     */
    public void scrollOnce() {
        PagerAdapter adapter = getAdapter();
        int currentItem = getCurrentItem();
        int totalCount;
        if (adapter == null || (totalCount = adapter.getCount()) <= 1) {
            return;
        }

        int nextItem = (direction == LEFT) ? --currentItem : ++currentItem;
        if (nextItem < 0) {
            if (isCycle) {
                setCurrentItem(totalCount - 1, isBorderAnimation);
            }
        } else if (nextItem == totalCount) {
            if (isCycle) {
                setCurrentItem(0, isBorderAnimation);
            }
        } else {
            setCurrentItem(nextItem, true);
        }
    }

    /**
     * <ul>
     * if stopScrollWhenTouch is true
     * <li>if event is down, stop auto scroll.</li>
     * <li>if event is up, start auto scroll again.</li>
     * </ul>
     */
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        int action = ev.getActionMasked();

        if (stopScrollWhenTouch) {
            if ((action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && isAutoScroll) {
                isStopByTouch = true;
                stopAutoScroll();
            } else if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && isStopByTouch) {
                startAutoScroll();
            }
        }

        if (slideBorderMode == SLIDE_BORDER_MODE_TO_PARENT || slideBorderMode == SLIDE_BORDER_MODE_CYCLE) {
            float touchX = ev.getX();
            if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                downX = touchX;
            }
            int currentItem = getCurrentItem();
            PagerAdapter adapter = getAdapter();
            int pageCount = adapter == null ? 0 : adapter.getCount();
            /**
             * current index is first one and slide to right or current index is last one and slide to left.<br/>
             * if slide border mode is to parent, then requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent false.<br/>
             * else scroll to last one when current item is first one, scroll to first one when current item is last
             * one.
             */
            if ((currentItem == 0 && downX <= touchX) || (currentItem == pageCount - 1 && downX >= touchX)) {
                if (slideBorderMode == SLIDE_BORDER_MODE_TO_PARENT) {
                    getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                } else {
                    if (pageCount > 1) {
                        setCurrentItem(pageCount - currentItem - 1, isBorderAnimation);
                    }
                    getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                }
                return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
            }
        }
        getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    private static class MyHandler extends Handler {

        private final WeakReference<AutoScrollViewPager> autoScrollViewPager;

        public MyHandler(AutoScrollViewPager autoScrollViewPager) {
            this.autoScrollViewPager = new WeakReference<AutoScrollViewPager>(autoScrollViewPager);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);

            if (msg.what == SCROLL_WHAT) {
                AutoScrollViewPager pager = this.autoScrollViewPager.get();
                if (pager != null) {
                    pager.scroller.setScrollDurationFactor(pager.autoScrollFactor);
                    pager.scrollOnce();
                    pager.scroller.setScrollDurationFactor(pager.swipeScrollFactor);
                    pager.sendScrollMessage(pager.interval + pager.scroller.getDuration());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * get auto scroll time in milliseconds, default is {@link #DEFAULT_INTERVAL}
     * 
     * @return the interval
     */
    public long getInterval() {
        return interval;
    }

    /**
     * set auto scroll time in milliseconds, default is {@link #DEFAULT_INTERVAL}
     * 
     * @param interval the interval to set
     */
    public void setInterval(long interval) {
        this.interval = interval;
    }

    /**
     * get auto scroll direction
     * 
     * @return {@link #LEFT} or {@link #RIGHT}, default is {@link #RIGHT}
     */
    public int getDirection() {
        return (direction == LEFT) ? LEFT : RIGHT;
    }

    /**
     * set auto scroll direction
     * 
     * @param direction {@link #LEFT} or {@link #RIGHT}, default is {@link #RIGHT}
     */
    public void setDirection(int direction) {
        this.direction = direction;
    }

    /**
     * whether automatic cycle when auto scroll reaching the last or first item, default is true
     * 
     * @return the isCycle
     */
    public boolean isCycle() {
        return isCycle;
    }

    /**
     * set whether automatic cycle when auto scroll reaching the last or first item, default is true
     * 
     * @param isCycle the isCycle to set
     */
    public void setCycle(boolean isCycle) {
        this.isCycle = isCycle;
    }

    /**
     * whether stop auto scroll when touching, default is true
     * 
     * @return the stopScrollWhenTouch
     */
    public boolean isStopScrollWhenTouch() {
        return stopScrollWhenTouch;
    }

    /**
     * set whether stop auto scroll when touching, default is true
     * 
     * @param stopScrollWhenTouch
     */
    public void setStopScrollWhenTouch(boolean stopScrollWhenTouch) {
        this.stopScrollWhenTouch = stopScrollWhenTouch;
    }

    /**
     * get how to process when sliding at the last or first item
     * 
     * @return the slideBorderMode {@link #SLIDE_BORDER_MODE_NONE}, {@link #SLIDE_BORDER_MODE_TO_PARENT},
     *         {@link #SLIDE_BORDER_MODE_CYCLE}, default is {@link #SLIDE_BORDER_MODE_NONE}
     */
    public int getSlideBorderMode() {
        return slideBorderMode;
    }

    /**
     * set how to process when sliding at the last or first item
     * 
     * @param slideBorderMode {@link #SLIDE_BORDER_MODE_NONE}, {@link #SLIDE_BORDER_MODE_TO_PARENT},
     *        {@link #SLIDE_BORDER_MODE_CYCLE}, default is {@link #SLIDE_BORDER_MODE_NONE}
     */
    public void setSlideBorderMode(int slideBorderMode) {
        this.slideBorderMode = slideBorderMode;
    }

    /**
     * whether animating when auto scroll at the last or first item, default is true
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public boolean isBorderAnimation() {
        return isBorderAnimation;
    }

    /**
     * set whether animating when auto scroll at the last or first item, default is true
     * 
     * @param isBorderAnimation
     */
    public void setBorderAnimation(boolean isBorderAnimation) {
        this.isBorderAnimation = isBorderAnimation;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**Try to add a dependency in gradle**

implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

And replace layout_behavior with below properties
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" '

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
```

Comment: I have use AutoScrollViewPager so in normal viewpager it will worked but i am asking for AutoScrollViewPager is there any customization any one know.