# How do I adjust interactions with the ScrollView, such that users do not accidentally scroll in the wrong direction?

Tags: android, scrollview

We have and app that has a scroll view with items that can be paged (left + right).

We are finding that users keeps scrolling (up+down) when they try to swipe (left+right), particularly when the use the phone one-handed and using their thumb to swipe.

Through physical experimentation the up+down action appears to kick in earlier than we'd like i.e the cut off point appears to be

> |dy| > |dx| => up-down action
>
> |dy| < |dx| => left-right action

I'd like to know if it is possible to change the swipe action such that we only scroll up and down when say the the dy > 1.4*dx i.e. make the angle of attack significantly more in the vertical plane.

I hope the above makes sense.

I am thinking I may need to intercept the gestures and only pass through those that meet my more restrictive criteria to the underlying views.

Comment: I eventually used a tweak of the VerticalScrollView suggestion from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646028/android-horizontalscrollview-within-scrollview-touch-handling

Comment: What tweak?  I couldn't see where those methods allowed modifiying dx or dy.

Comment: tweak means I made a slight alteration to the code in the link

Comment: Your question mentions adjusting the "sensitivity" of the scroll, which I don't see as possible hence my question of what tweak did you make.  I assume your need was actually about constraining scrolling to get the interaction needed.

Comment: If I recall correctly (and it was 3 years ago) I used the MotionEvents to calc |dx| and |dy| and only up/down if |dy| > 1.4* |dx| - sorry no longer have the source code to hand to help further.