# ViewPager in ScrollView no Scrollbar

Tags: android, xml

in my xml style I use a android.support.v4.view.ViewPager within a ScrollView. The problem is that I dont get a scrollbar. The ViewPager itself behaves also strange when I slide from one page to another.

Setting the ScrollView to a fixed height e.g. 1200dip helps to scroll but doesnt show the ViewPager.
Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fadeScrollbars="true"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >


    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/menu"
            />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646028/android-horizontalscrollview-within-scrollview-touch-handling found the solution

Comment: Post an answer to your question and validate your own. I lost my time getting to this page thinking it was not resolved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you don't get a scrollbar is because your `ViewPager` (and `RelativeLayout`) has it's height set to `match_parent` instead of `wrap_content`. This causes it to match the dimensions of your `ScrollView`, which kind of defeats the purpose of the `ScrollView` in the first place.. The contents of your `ScrollView` should be higher/taller than your `ScrollView` itself.

To conclude, you should set both your `RelativeLayout`'s height and your `ViewPager`'s height to `wrap_content`. Also, you didn't set the order/position in which you want `RelativeLayout`'s children to appear; you might want to change that (or use `LinearLayout` instead). Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fadeScrollbars="true"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/menu" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I copied your xml but it doesnt scroll either. I think theres a fundamental problem with ViewPager in scrollView?

Comment: Yeah, like the answer in the link you provided above says, you can fix this by extending `ScrollView` and overriding it's `onInterceptTouchEvent(...)`-method. You should provide an answer to your own post and accept it.