# veiwpager(add content dynamically but not increase size) on scroll view in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-scrollview

I'm trying to make my view pager dynamically but it not run which i want. 
`android:layout_height="match_parent"` and `android:layout_height="Wrap_content"` give me same or i say **not scroll vertically**.

But if `android:layout_height="1000dp"` its scroll fine(**i'm adding view on runtime**).

**below my xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/regibar"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp" >
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <biz.xicom.defindme.profileuser.TabPageIndicator
                android:id="@+id/indicator"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/tabs_bg"
                android:fillViewport="true" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

or

```
                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Study so many link and also implemented but not achieve my task.

[ViewPager in ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034030/viewpager-in-scrollview)

[ViewPager inside a ScrollView does not scroll correclty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381697/viewpager-inside-a-scrollview-does-not-scroll-correclty)

[ViewPager in ScrollView no Scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185457/viewpager-in-scrollview-no-scrollbar)

Comment: maybe this can help you https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager/

Comment: @Yume117 thanks for rplying but not use full !!!!