# ViewPager inside of scrollview dont works

Tags: android, touch, scrollview, android-viewpager, fragment

I have a ViewPager inisde of a ScrollView, and the ViewPager dont works correctly. I know, this question is similar, and I googled and read some solutions. Also, behind of the ScrollView I have some stacked fragments. I tried this [HorizontalScrollView within ScrollView Touch Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646028/android-horizontalscrollview-within-scrollview-touch-handling) (extending the viewpager and the scrollview) and it works better, but not perfect. I think that the stacked fragments are capturing the Touch event.

Have somebody this problems? Thanks

EDIT: I add the code.

### Custom scrollview:

```
public class ScrollViewS extends ScrollView {
    /* THIS COMMENT CODE IS THE OTHER SOLUTION
    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
    View.OnTouchListener mGestureListener;

    public ScrollViewS(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new YScrollDetector());
        setFadingEdgeLength(0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev) && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    // Return false if we're scrolling in the x direction  
    class YScrollDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            if(Math.abs(distanceY) > Math.abs(distanceX)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    */
    private float xDistance, yDistance, lastX, lastY;

    public ScrollViewS(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                xDistance = yDistance = 0f;
                lastX = ev.getX();
                lastY = ev.getY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                final float curX = ev.getX();
                final float curY = ev.getY();
                xDistance += Math.abs(curX - lastX);
                yDistance += Math.abs(curY - lastY);
                lastX = curX;
                lastY = curY;
                if(xDistance > yDistance)
                    return false;
        }

        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

### ViewPager code:

```
public class ViewPagerS extends ViewPager {

    public ViewPagerS(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // Tell our parent to stop intercepting our events!
        boolean ret = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        if (ret) {
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

### And the XML is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/fondoapp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <com.geo.sov.customviews.ScrollViewS
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/borde_redondeado"
        android:id="@+id/scrollview_fragmentaccounts"
         >

       <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/x"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
        >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_accounts"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <com.geo.sov.customviews.ViewPagerS
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="95dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFFFF" /> 

            <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                android:id="@+id/indicator"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:padding="10dip"
                app:pageColor="#88FF0000"
                app:radius="3dp"
                app:strokeColor="#FF666666"
                app:strokeWidth="1dp" />

(........)
```

When I start my app, I have one fragment, and if the user logon correctly y change it with the following code:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

Fragment f = new AccountsFragment();

fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment, f);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

And I experiment some problems with fragments. When I change to AccountsFragments, if i touch in a empty space, the touch events pass to the logon fragment. I think that the scrollview and viewpager are correctly, and the problem is the fragments that they are intercepting the events.

Comment: Ahmad, sorry. Now i added the code

Comment: Add onInterceptTouchEvent in ViewPager is enough for me.