# ListView inside Viewpager - no scrolling

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager, android-listfragment

I want to place a `ListView (ListFragment)` inside a `ViewPager` using a `FragmentPagerAdapter`.
But the ListViews scrolling functionallity seems to be disabled when doing this (I cant scroll up and down). Here is my code:

**main.xml**

```
<include layout="@layout/prisniveau_info" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@color/light_gray"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="#fff" />
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

**adapter:**

> ```
>  public class MyAdapter extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter
>      {
> public MyAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm)
> {
>      super(fm);
> }
> @Override
> public int getCount()
> {
>     return 2;
> }       
> @Override
> public Fragment getItem(int position)
> {
>     Fragment fragment = null;
>     if(position==0)
>     {
>         fragment = new MyListFragment();                
>     }
>     else if(position==1)
>     {
>         fragment = new MyMapFragment();
>     }
>     return fragment;
> }       
> @Override
> public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
> {
>     switch (position)
>     {
>         case 0:
>         return  getString(R.string.title_list).toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault());
>         case 1:
>             return getString(R.string.title_map).toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault());
>         }
>         return null;
>     }       
>     public String getFragmentTag(int index)
>     {
>          return "android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":" + index;
>     }
> }
> ```

Is it possible to make the `ListView` scrollable inside a `ViewPager`?

Comment: I just discovered that the scrollview works on my HTC Legend (Froyo), but not on my Nexus Galaxy (Jelly Bean)

Comment: But it wont scroll the whole list..

Answer (score 0):

i have found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646028/android-horizontalscrollview-within-scrollview-touch-handling). There might be the problem in handling touch events properly for a HorizontalScrollView inside a regular ScrollView, but the solution to that problem may seems to apply to this one too.

Comment: I have not been able to get the ListView scolling back by implementing some of the code from the solution your are writing about :f