# view pager not smooth when embedded within scrollview?

Tags: android, image, android-viewpager

I have requirement like play store app  where there is view pager with images and videos 
and scroll to view details .Unfortunately when user scrolls the scroll is jumpy but if i remove the scrollview the view pager works perfectly fine .

The layout look and feel is something like this 
http://cl.ly/MBRB

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"  android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:background="@drawable/loading_image"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/product_image_pager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/titles"
            style="@style/CirclePageIndicator"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/app_screen_menu" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Btw i am loading images from server .

Thanks

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your layout?

Comment: The Play Store does not use a layout like this. The scrollable content is inside the pages, not outside the pager. You can tell this by actually using the Play Store app -- the indicator at the top does not scroll, as it would with your approach. I suspect that it also does not use a `ScrollView`, but rather some form of `AdapterView` (possibly a custom one).

Comment: Edited with the image http://cl.ly/MBRB

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using 2 scrollisteners

- A viewpager uses a scrolllistener
- A scrollview uses a scrolllistener

These two scrollistener are fighting for the ScrollEvent.
You can solve this by implementing `onInterceptTouch`. In this method you can decide who wins the fight over the ScrollEvent

Take a look at this [protected post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646028/android-horizontalscrollview-within-scrollview-touch-handling) regarding a similair issue containing 2 scrollviews

Comment: yes,100% true brother, I eliminated my scroll view from xml design side and it done.