# How to use over scroll mode in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

## Problem

I need to give some priority for scrolling events in my Activity.

I'm using aiCharts (charts library) and I need to zoom, pan, etc. on my areas. Without any `ScrollViews` it works fine, but, if I use the mentioned `Layout`, these features works bad. I think because of priority of views.

## Possible solution

I tried to use `setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS);` on views that need to be on "top" of `ScrollView` and `HorizontalScrollView` but doesn't work properly.

## Layout

```
 <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/screen_relative_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </RelativeLayout>        
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </ScrollView>
```

All my views are added programmatically by adding to RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Change your RelativeLayout so that the `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`
Also do your own custom scrollview so that it intercepts the movement and nothing else:

```
public class VerticalScrollView extends ScrollView {
private float xDistance, yDistance, lastX, lastY;

public VerticalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            xDistance = yDistance = 0f;
            lastX = ev.getX();
            lastY = ev.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            final float curX = ev.getX();
            final float curY = ev.getY();
            xDistance += Math.abs(curX - lastX);
            yDistance += Math.abs(curY - lastY);
            lastX = curX;
            lastY = curY;
            if(xDistance > yDistance)
                return false;
    }

    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}
}
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7703740/1182971)

Let me know how that worked!

Comment: It works if the RelativeLayout is not scrollable. If the view dimension is bigger than screen resolution, scroll become active and I  have the same issue.

Comment: you have to create a custom scrollview so that the only touches you intercept are the ones from x to y here is a sample: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2655740/1182971  
And a custom horizontal scrollview that also just intercepts when you go from left to right and right to left. Hope it helps you.