# Set Viewpager height inside Scrollview in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-scrollview

I have to show a viewpager (An image and text below the image in pager row) inside a scrollview. I'm downloading the image, text from web and showing in pager rows. I wrapped viewpager inside a srollview to support the landscape mode too.

```
 <com.xxx.myapp.android.ui.CustomScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="800dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />  
    </LinearLayout>
</com.xxx.myapp.android.ui.CustomScrollView>
```

And here is [CustomScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2655740). The problem is How can I set the view pager height based on its children height so that I can scroll the screen till the view pager item ends only. If I set view pager height to wrapcontent, nothing is showing in viewpager. If I set some 800dp then I can see the pager items but there is unnecessary scrolling in the screen. I dont want my scrollview to be scrolled beyond the pager childrens height. Please help me.

Comment: Don't give fix height to View pager..

Comment: Did you solved? Facing same issue

Comment: @Gayathri please share class of com.xxx.myapp.android.ui.CustomScrollView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your pager row inside CustomScrollView instead of wrapping the pager inside CustomScrollview. And Don't fix height of Viewpager as Piyush Gupath commented. Use wrapcontent.

Answer (score 24):

To fix the height of the viewpager we can customize the viewpager class.

```
public class WrapContentViewPager extends ViewPager {

private int mCurrentPagePosition = 0;

public WrapContentViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public WrapContentViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    try {
        View child = getChildAt(mCurrentPagePosition);
        if (child != null) {
            child.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            int h = child.getMeasuredHeight();
            heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(h, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}

public void reMeasureCurrentPage(int position) {
    mCurrentPagePosition = position;
    requestLayout();
}
}
```

where this reMeasureCurrentPage should be called at viewpager onPageSelected callback.and CustomScrollView is the parent view.

Comment: I need a viewpager with the height of its currently showing child. 
This is the perfect solution among plenty of answers on SOF.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I have a GridView in the ViewPager contents though.

Comment: worked for me, but resize viewpager height when scrolled to last item

Answer (score 9):

```
mViewPager = new ViewPager(mContext) {
        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

            View view = getChildAt(this.getCurrentItem());
            if (view != null) {
                view.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            }
            setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec, view));
        }

        private int measureHeight(int measureSpec, View view) {
            int result = 0;
            int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
            int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

            if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
                result = specSize;
            } else {
                // set the height from the base view if available
                if (view != null) {
                    result = view.getMeasuredHeight();
                }
                if (specMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
                    result = Math.min(result, specSize);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this way

```
<com.xxx.myapp.android.ui.CustomScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />  
    </LinearLayout>
</com.xxx.myapp.android.ui.CustomScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best and easy solution :

1) Inside your custom ViewPager Class -

```
override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
    var heightMeasureSpec = heightMeasureSpec
    val mode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec)
    // Unspecified means that the ViewPager is in a ScrollView WRAP_CONTENT.
    // At Most means that the ViewPager is not in a ScrollView WRAP_CONTENT.
    if (mode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED || mode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
        // super has to be called in the beginning so the child views can be initialized.
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
        var height = 0
        for (i in 0 until childCount) {
            val child = getChildAt(i)
            child.measure(
                widthMeasureSpec,
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
            )
            val h = child.measuredHeight
            if (h > height) height = h
        }
        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
    }
    // super has to be called again so the new specs are treated as exact measurements
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
}
```

2) While Setting the adapter to your ViewPager -

```
val viewPagerAdapter = ViewPagerAdapter(fragmentList, supportFragmentManager)
view_pager.adapter = viewPagerAdapter
view_pager.measure(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)`
view_pager.currentItem = 0
```