# Android - ViewPager tab not showing first time

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have a tablayout with viewpager and a recyclerview inside... I've override the onMeasure method... The first time I open the fragment, the fragment inside the viewpager not show, but if i change tab it appear and if i go back to the tab that doesn't show, it begin to show... Can some one help me please!!!

I Think i saw is the viewpager get visible on screen if it fit on the screen, if i need to scroll the screen to see the viewpager it begin hided until i go to another tab and back again to see the content.

I got diferent sizes of contents inside the viewpager, that's why i need to use a custom view pager and override the onMeasure...

The source code below...

THE VIEW PAGER

```
public class CustomPager extends ViewPager {

    private int mCurrentPagePosition = 0;

    public CustomPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        try {
            View child = getChildAt(mCurrentPagePosition);
            if (child != null) {
                child.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
                int h = child.getMeasuredHeight();
                heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(h, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    public void reMeasureCurrentPage(int position) {
        mCurrentPagePosition = position;
        requestLayout();
    }
}
```

THE SCROLLVIEW

```
public class CustomScrollView extends ScrollView {

    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new YScrollDetector());
        setFadingEdgeLength(0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev)
                && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    // Return false if we're scrolling in the x direction
    class YScrollDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                                float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            return (Math.abs(distanceY) > Math.abs(distanceX));
        }
    }
}
```

THE LAYOUT

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="br.com.ole.oleconsignado.ui.fragment.main.LastEntriesFragment">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/vw_divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_mdpi"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_mdpi"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_mdpi"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_mdpi"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_mdpi"
        android:background="@color/colorGrey"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorLightBlue"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorLightBlue"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_mdpi"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_mdpi">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tab_national"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/title_national" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tab_international"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/title_international" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <br.com.ole.oleconsignado.util.CustomScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <br.com.ole.oleconsignado.util.CustomPager
            android:id="@+id/vp_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_mdpi" />

    </br.com.ole.oleconsignado.util.CustomScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I realy don't know why it happen... Please, help me!

Here some examples similar...

[Set Viewpager height inside Scrollview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20000018/set-viewpager-height-inside-scrollview-in-android)

[getchildat() method returns null for last position (3rd Fragment in my case) Fragment for WarpContent ViewPager Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42761247/getchildat-method-returns-null-for-last-position-3rd-fragment-in-my-case-fra)

[ViewPager wrap_content not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34484833/viewpager-wrap-content-not-working)

[Android - ViewPager tab not showing first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44008830/android-viewpager-tab-not-showing-first-time)

Comment: Why do you need a custom `ViewPager` and don't simply use the default `ViewPager` ?

Comment: Because if i use the default viewpager, i'm needing to set height="xdp" to see the viewpager.. With that custom viewpager it's showing... I've edited my anwser

Comment: why not `wrap_content` or `match_parent` ?

Comment: I didn't understand why i wrap_content not getting the size... :(

Comment: one of the reasons would be because you overridden the `onMeasure()` method.

Comment: this line `int h = child.getMeasuredHeight();` is probably returning 0, and this line `heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(h, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);` followed by this line `super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);` tells it you want it to be exactly 0 high.  But then again, this is just me supposing - the debugger will tell you exactly what's going wrong and where.

Comment: I'll check the results when pass the first time to dont show nothing... and add on my question

Comment: The first time is not finding child... it comming null that's the reason its not making the height dynamic... and when i change the tab, the child return something...

Comment: and whats the value of `heightMeasureSpec` when the child is null, that is being passed into `super.onMeasure(...);` ?

Comment: Yes... the super.onMeasure(...)

Comment: I need to know why the getChildAt(int) not finding my view...

Comment: The `ViewPager` is instantiated, then it measures itself, then it instantiates it's children with the correct measure specs so they can measure themselves. That'd be my first guess, so the first time `ViewPager::onMeasure()` is called, perhaps it doesn't have any children yet?

Comment: You can always look at the ViewPager's sourcecode to find out the real reason though.

Comment: I found the error... inside my fragment that i inflate on view pager have a recyclerview... and its setting the layout manager after pass on the getChildAt(int)... But thx bro!

Comment: Hey man... I didn't figured how i can call my recyclerview before call onMeasure from viewpager... The viewpager only have the size of my recyclerview after i call LayoutManager from recyclerview... Can you help me please?

Comment: Help you with what? update the question with additional info and i'll try to see whether i can see something.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I couldn't understan your use-case completely but I think I can help.

Are You Trying to get any sort Dimensional-Measurements from the activity?

If Yes Then unfortunately the activities and fragments are not completely generated until onPause()

but you can try to do this-

Create a variable of your parent layout in your activity ;

```
    RelativeLayout canvas;

            canvas = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.canvas);

 canvas.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new 
 ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

 canvas.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

     /* Code to get dimensional measurements */


        }
    });
```

Hope It Helps :)