# Nested viewpager fragments in android 2.3.3 and 4.0

Tags: android, nested, android-viewpager, fragment, android-2.3-gingerbread

I'm having lots of issues in swiping fragment in code running 2.3.3 .I am using a viewpager with fragments which contains another viewpage and fragments . The hierarachy is :

VIEWPAGER1

FRAGMENT1

VIEWPAGER2

FRAGMETN2

Each viewpager can scroll independently on Android 4.0 + but when I run the same code on Android 2.3.3 only VIEWPAGER1 is able to swipe, VIEWPAGER2 is not able to swipe

Is there any possible workaroud for this prolem . Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Very old question but it may help someone
Here is a solution proposed here which can work for you as it worked for me
The point is to use an overriden ViewPager class for your embedded ViewPager

[Android - HorizontalScrollView within ScrollView Touch Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2655740/1539581)

It is for scrollview but it works for a viewpager embedded in another scrollview