# Android: Disable Scroll view for horizontal scrolling

Tags: android, scrollview

Is it possible to stop scrolling vertically when the user swipes horizontally.

Here is my scroll view.

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/thirdSeperator"
    android:layout_below="@+id/upSeperator"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rlt_right_side_bar"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rlt_left_category" >

    <RelativeLayout>

     Other views

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The vertically scrolling working fine.

The inside view have horizontal scrolling.Independently they were working fine. But when i add the scroll view , the scroll is not smooth. Is there a way to disable scroll view when user swipes horizontally?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646028/android-horizontalscrollview-within-scrollview-touch-handling