# android- How to use ViewPager inside scrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-scrollview

I've a layout that has 3 parts . One of them is viewpager . I need to scroll the screen .
i've this code but the problem is this ,the viewpager is not showing at all .

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/s11" />

    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:background="#CC0001"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I make viewpager to wrap the free space and fill the parent and show its content ?

thanks you

Comment: did you put any thing in viewpager ?

Comment: @mmlooloo  yes, I've 3 fragments . If I don't pus scrollView , it works fine but when I put scrollview , the viewpager don't show anything

Comment: have you tried setting `android:fillViewport="true"` for your scrollview?

Comment: @mmlooloo I tried this , didn't work

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646028/android-horizontalscrollview-within-scrollview-touch-handling