# onTouch() method doesn't receive ACTION_DOWN

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout, swiperefreshlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I have an app, where I need to display multiple `RecyclerView`s inside `ConstraintLayout` inside `NestedScrollView` inside `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

All `RecyclerView`s have `LinearLayoutManager` with horizontal orientation.

So, my current layout tree looks like this:

```
<SwipeRefreshLayout>
    <NestedScrollView>
        <ConstraintLayout>
            <RecyclerView></RecyclerView>
            <RecyclerView></RecyclerView>
            <RecyclerView></RecyclerView>
        ...
        </ConstraintLayout>
    </NestedScrollView>
</SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is something similar to what Google Play app has on Home screen.

My problem is such, that `RecyclerView`s are way too picky about what can be considered a horizontal swipe.

I tried to `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` but to no avail.

Then I started to look into `onTouch()` methods of everything above `RecyclerView`s and I found, that `ACTION_DOWN` of `MotionEvent` does appear only if I scroll very slowly - anything, that can be considered a swipe/fling doesn't produce `ACTION_DOWN`, only `ACTION_MOVE` and `ACTION_UP`.

Is there something I don't know about this construction? Does some view consume `ACTION_DOWN`?

And side question - are there examples of recreating not only appearance of Google Play Home screen, but also a feel? Their horizontal lists are way more forgiving, when it comes to horizontal scroll.

**EDIT:** Added `OnItemTouchListener` to all my `RecyclerView`s. It intercepts ALL swipes/flings/scrolls correctly, but not all trigger OnSwipeListener. Here's code. Side note: OnSwipeListener is taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26387629) with slight addition of `onScroll` method

```
public class MyOnItemTouchListener extends RecyclerView.SimpleOnItemTouchListener {

    private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector;
    private OnSwipeListener mListener = new OnSwipeListener() {

        @Override public boolean onSwipe(Direction direction) {
            Log.d("Tag", "OnItemListener direction=" + direction);
            return super.onSwipe(direction);
        }
    };

    public HomeOnItemTouchListener(Context context) {
        mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(context, mListener);
    }

    @Override public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        Log.d("Tag", "OnItemListener intercept MotionEvent=" + e);
        mDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(rv, e);
    }

    @Override public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        Log.d("Tag", "OnItemListener onTouch MotionEvent=" + e);
        mDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
        super.onTouchEvent(rv, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: is your recycler view's orientation horizontal?

Comment: @MohammedJunaid yes it is

Comment: Did you try removing NestedScrollView as that might be interfering with your recycler view scrolling?

Comment: Yes, I tried to implement it as RecyclerView with RecyclerViews as it's elements - no result. What I'm trying right now is I set OnItemTouchListeners to each RecyclerView - as I see, they intercept all touch events, even those, that are not scrolling them...

Comment: can you post your onItemTouchListener code?

Comment: Added to question under EDIT

Comment: Okay, looks like I found (after ~2 days of searching) solution for my problem - https://stackoverflow.com/a/37074838 is what I was looking for - it allows more lenient side scroll.