# Pager-like behavior in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement a ViewPager-like behavior for a horizontal `RecyclerView`. The data from the adapter should inflate and bind as normal, but the navigation through the `Recycler` should be handled differently. When the user swipes (or attempts to scroll), I move the `Recycler` one item in that direction, sticking it to the left side.

I already have all the item transition logic. I am using a custom `LayoutManager`, which overrides `onSmoothScrollToPosition()` with a custom `LinearSmoothScroller()` which does the item to-the-left sticking.

The question is - how can I override the scrolling behavior of the `RecyclerView` to intercept the swipes and handle them myself? I tried disabling scrolling in the `LayoutManager` and then intercepting the gesture in an `onTouchListener`, but this does not seem to work. Does the `RecyclerView` framework have a clean way to handle this?

Comment: I think intercepting the gesture in `onTouchListener` should already do the trick. What's not working about that solution?

Comment: Well, It does not intercept anything for some reason. I assume this may be caused by the fact that the horizontal Recycler is in a page of a larger pager (Fragment Pager for sections of the app) and it just passes the gesture to the top pager :(

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I managed to get it to work, turns out I had to implement onScroll() in the SimpleGestureListener, not just onFling(). However, there is a problem with that as well - the onScroll() method will trigger multiple times, resulting in the Recycler going through all items at once. Any patterns to handle this?

Answer (score 31):

The native Android solution covered in [this](https://rubensousa.github.io/2016/08/recyclerviewsnap) post was a super easy way to get the RecyclerView to behave like a ViewPager.

Relevant bits:

> The 24.2.0 version of the support library introduced two new classes (SnapHelper and LinearSnapHelper) that should be used to handle snapping in a RecyclerView.
>   ....
>   The only code needed is:

`SnapHelper snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper();
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);`

`SnapHelper snapHelper = new GravitySnapHelper(Gravity.START); 
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(startRecyclerView);`

Comment: Please include the relevant part of your linked page in your answer. A link-only answer is not user friendly, and becomes totally useless if the link dies!

Comment: PagerSnapHelper is another class available that extends SnapHelper. It works well if you want paging-like behavior.

Comment: Was one step away from giving up the search and stat coding it myself, then I found your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Attach your `RecyclerView` to `SnapHelper`

[Official Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearSnapHelper)

[Library](https://github.com/rubensousa/RecyclerViewSnap)

Comment: And how will this help?

Comment: @Kelevandos use custom scrollview to detect YScroll. [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646028/android-horizontalscrollview-within-scrollview-touch-handling)

Comment: You mean a ScrollView wrapper for the RecyclerView? This could work, but I hope there is a way to handle this in a clean way using the RecyclerView framework :-(

Comment: You should go with this, believe me I've done R&D and came up with this. working smoothly without any issue

Answer (score 2):

there is a library [layoutmanagers](https://github.com/apptik/MultiView/tree/master/layoutmanagers) exactly for this.

the one that you need is [ViewPagerLayoutManager](https://github.com/apptik/MultiView/blob/master/layoutmanagers/src/main/java/io/apptik/multiview/layoutmanagers/ViewPagerLayoutManager.java). It is based on the same idea you already have but more extended and handles multiple cases. It basically scrolls until there is a change of page & state then takes over and adjust to the right page.

To use it you just need to set it as a normal Layout manager:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new ViewPagerLayoutManager(getActivity()));
```

for more info and examples check [here](https://github.com/apptik/MultiView)

Comment: This does work, but it forces the recycler to work 100% like a pager, meaning one child visible at a time. This is not what I want :-(

Comment: you can simply use another one if you want to see or swipe multiple elements for example SnapperLinearLayoutManager

Comment: @djodjo how can I make it scroll horizontally ?

Comment: ok I found it 
new ViewPagerLayoutManager(this , LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL , false);