# SwipeGestureDetector change image from int [] to Imageview (Top & Bottom)

Tags: java, android, arrays, imageview, gesture

I need to take an image from an int Array and show then in Imageview when i swipe from bottom to top and top to bottom.

The GestureDetector works well but i want to take an image from an int [] and put then in Imageview when swipe.

Exemple :

```
int [] imageBank = new int[] {
            R.drawable.image0,
            R.drawable.image1,
            R.drawable.image2,
            R.drawable.image3,
            R.drawable.image4, };
```

Swipe top to bottom, 
take image 0 from [ ], 
show in Imageview

Swipe top to bottom, 
take image 1 from [ ], 
show in Imageview

Swipe bottom to top, 
take image 0 from [ ], 
show in Imageview

Swipe bottom to top, 
take image 4 from [ ], 
show in Imageview

Complete MainActivity

```
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import driss.moodtracker.R;
import driss.moodtracker.component.SwipeGestureDetector;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



private SwipeGestureDetector gestureDetector;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gestureDetector = new SwipeGestureDetector(this);

    Button button_comment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button_calendar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
}



@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}



public void onSwipe(SwipeGestureDetector.SwipeDirection direction) {

    ImageView imagePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    ConstraintLayout currentLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);


    // ARRAY OF SMILEYS LIST

    int [] arraySmileys = new int[] {
            R.drawable.smiley_super_happy,
            R.drawable.smiley_happy,
            R.drawable.smiley_normal,
            R.drawable.smiley_disappointed,
            R.drawable.smiley_sad,
    };


   //  HOW CAN I DO ?

    String message = "";
    switch (direction) {
        case LEFT_TO_RIGHT:
            message = "Left to right swipe";
            break;
        case RIGHT_TO_LEFT:
            message = "Right to left swipe";
            break;
        case TOP_TO_BOTTOM:
            imagePic.setImageResource(R.drawable.smiley_disappointed);
            currentLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.faded_red);
            message = "Top to bottom swipe";
            break;
        case BOTTOM_TO_TOP:
            currentLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.light_sage);
            imagePic.setImageResource(R.drawable.smiley_super_happy);
            message = " Bottom to top swipe";
            break;

    }
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


}
```

Thanks you for your help

A new student.

Answer (score 0):

Define a 'counter' (integer variable) to store the index of your integer array. Now based on swipe detected, if user swipe from bottom to up increment the counter and set that index item's image to your imageview and vice versa for up to bottom.

Example code :

```
int counter = 0;

public void swipe() {
    switch (direction) {
    case LEFT_TO_RIGHT:
        message = "Left to right swipe";
        break;

    case RIGHT_TO_LEFT:
        message = "Right to left swipe";
        break;

    case TOP_TO_BOTTOM:
        if(counter > 0) {
            counter--;
            imagePic.setImageResource(arraySmileys[counter]);
        }
        break;

    case BOTTOM_TO_TOP:
        if(counter < arraySmileys.length()) {
            counter++;
            imagePic.setImageResource(arraySmileys[counter]);
        }
        break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you ! it's Working !

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `ViewPager` or `RecyclerView` with `ViewPager`-like [behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36329150/pager-like-behavior-in-recyclerview) instead of `GestureDetector`